# How to Insert into NHibernate DB after NHibernate Session

Tags: nhibernate

Let's say if I encounter an error in NHibernate db update, and when such an exception is thrown, I want to log it in the log table in the db, via NHibernate again.

Now, since I can't [reuse NHibernate session after an exception thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493660/nhibernate-handling-an-itransaction-exception-so-that-new-transactions-can-conti/501727#501727), I will get an error when I log into the log table. How to best handle this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Open a new session.

Or use a logging framework like log4net with ADO.NET appender and do it completely separately out of NHibernate environment.

Answer (score 2):

IMO logging should be a [cross cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) of your application. You should not try to reuse the same session in order to log errors. NHibernate already uses [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html). All you need is to configure an appender that will write logs to the SQL database.